# Can Create, Update and Delete actions be done in Salesforce REST API using Postman?

Tags: rest, postman, salesforce

I am attempting to use Postman to perform CRUD operations in Salesforce. I am able to do Read operations, but not the other 3 operations. My Postman is obviously authenticated and my account is authorized in Salesforce to do the other operations. My user's profile is API Enabled. But I can't do the other 3. Does Salesforce REST API just not work for write operations?

Comment: Export your commands from Postman (as raw HTTP or curl), edit sensitive data out (company/sandbox name, session id) and share here? What errors (http error code and body ideally) are you getting? Is your user's profile enabled to do create/edit/delete on that object?

Comment: @eyescream yeah all objects are on View All and Modify All. It's giving a 200, but Salesforce isn't performing the action.